# Calculating number of T-units in a given sentence using Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

I've been working on a second language development project. I need to calculate the [t-unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L2_Syntactic_Complexity_Analyzer) of a given sentence using Python. For example, for the following sentences:

```
The man did not like water.
```

1 t-unit (The man did not like water)

```
The man did not like water although he lived by the sea.
```

1 t-unit (The man did not like water although he lived by the sea)

```
The man never liked water and he certainly did not like living in the swamp with her grandparents.
```

1 t-unit (The man never liked water)
1 t-unit (he certainly did not like living in the swamp with her grandparents)

```
The man did not like water or juice.
```

1 t-unit (The man did not like water or juice)

I've checked out nltk, spacy and stanford nlp (stanza) but found out that they don't include such t-unit detection at all.

I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227103/clause-extraction-long-sentence-segmentation-in-python) but it is about clause extraction.

Any idea how I can detect such t-units using Python?

Comment: Well, the post you cited does do clause extraction, and your task is really just identifying which clauses connected by conjunctions have subject and verb.  I would think that's the right place to start.

Comment: It seems like the root of the problem is trying to identify compound sentences. Could you not look for conjunctions and semicolons? You'll have to have a way to determine if the conjunction is being used as a conjunction, but that might be easier than trying to determine the clauses.

Comment: It sounds like a T-unit is roughly equivalent to an S in a constituency parse. Unfortunately constituency parsers aren't used much any more and I'm not sure there are any you can just use. Using a dependency parse to find verbs that have subjects should be pretty easy though. Check the parsing chapters in the Jurafsky and Martin book, and maybe look into sentence simplification. https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/